# How to deploy Spring application on OpenShift?

Tags: openshift

I have a bunch of Spring applications (NOT Spring Boot!) that was developed for Karaf6 Fuse container. Now I have to deploy them on OpenShift.

If I open projects in RedHat Studio and install them via OpenShift explorer it fails.

I see the option to create new project for Karaf container but, this project is based on blueprint.xml in OSGI catalog. And my application has camel-context.xml in spring catalog. So i can't just copy project and deploy.

The only working solution a have for now is create new Spring Boot project and transfer functionality from old Spring application to new Spring Boot app. But it's too slow process.

Any ideas how to deploy Spring projects to OpenShift containers without porting process?

Comment: Why don't you create a docker image that you can deploy in OpenShift?

Comment: I don't know how to create docker images for this applictaions.

Comment: And here we have the problem. You should first learn how to use OpenShift and Docker and then figure out how to deploy your application.